# Hiding link for mobile users

Tags: html, mobile

The online scheduling tool I'm using currently only works for desktop users (not only the resolution, but interface doesn't work with touch input), so I'm trying to find a way to only show the link to the tool for desktop users and show a simple form for mobile users.

I've learned how to hide and show things based on resolution, but I'm not sure this is a good solution, as someone on a tablet would have the correct resolution, but still not be able to use

Answer (score 0):

Well from my experience I would opt for 2 "distinct ways" to resolve your issue.

#### First

is using WURFL lib, it support **almost** any device in market, excluding some particular feature phones.

You can view more here http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/php_index.php

and some capabilities WURFL "catch" http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/help_doc.php

in which I filtered some prop that can be useful for your problem:

- **is_wireless_device**
- **is_tablet**
- **xhtml_support_level**
- **resolution_width**
- **resolution_height**
- **pointing_method**

among others...

#### Second

Use responsive web design and media queries.

#### Final thoughts

I would opt for the first option, but that's just me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS media queries. They are the best way to go!

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  link {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to hide links for mobile devices is done with media queries, you were right about that. I usually use

```
a {

   display:none;
```

}

Or you can use jQuery

```
$(".yourlist .yourlink").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
```

})